# DevExtream MultiSelect DropDown box Customize the Appearance

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

In Angular 10 I am using the devExtream multi-select dropdown box now I want to show selected items in customizing like have selected 2 items in the drop-down box so it will show **2 items selected** on the drop-down.

The Html part

```
<div class="dx-field">
    <div class="dx-field-label">DropDownBox with embedded DataGrid</div>
    <div class="dx-field-value">
        <dx-drop-down-box
                [(value)]="gridBoxValue"
                valueExpr="ID"
                displayExpr="CompanyName"
                placeholder="Select a value..."
                [showClearButton]="true"
                [dataSource]="gridDataSource"
                (onValueChanged)="ValueChange($event)"
        >

            <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'content'">
                <dx-data-grid
                        [dataSource]="gridDataSource"
                        [columns]="['CompanyName']"
                        [selection]="{ mode: 'multiple' }"
                        [hoverStateEnabled]="true"
                        [paging]="{ enabled: true, pageSize: 10 }"
                        [filterRow]="{ visible: true }"
                        [scrolling]="{ mode: 'infinite' }"
                        [height]="345"
                        [(selectedRowKeys)]="gridBoxValue"
                >
                </dx-data-grid>
            </div>
        </dx-drop-down-box>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS file

```
    **gridDataSource: any;
  
  gridBoxValue: number[] = [];
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
      
        this.gridDataSource = this.makeAsyncDataSource(http);
       
    }

    makeAsyncDataSource(http) {
      return new CustomStore({
        loadMode: "raw",
        key: "ID",
        load: function() {
            return http.get("https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/JSDemos/data/customers.json")
                .toPromise();
        }
    });
  }

  

  ValueChange(e)
  {
   debugger;
 
  }**
```

Answer (score 0):

For this functionallity I recomend you to use a [tagBox](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxTagBox/) (looks like a [dropDownBox](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDropDownBox/) but the functionallity is diferent) instead of a dropDownBox but if you need for some reason you should try to add a [checkBox](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxCheckBox/) inside the content data.